# Extract the top 10 results per grouped item

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have 5000 lines of alarms for various machines. For each machine, I can sort the alarms and count the number of alarms with the same name. But I would like to focus on the top 10 most numerous alarms for each machine.

How can I limit the query result to the top 10 most numerous alarms for each machine ?

My current query:

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!1:50000;"select F, J, count(J) where L='Alarm' group by F,J";-1)
```

Comment: Query a query. You'll need to provide column headers if you want actual examples that apply to your table. Consider a pivot table as well

Answer (score 0):

You can make a separate query for each machine with e.g. `where F='Machine1'` and limit the results including `limit 10` into your query. Example:

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!1:50000;"select F, J, count(J) where L='Alarm' and F='Machine1' group by F,J limit 10";-1)
```